# Automatic upload in Zend-Studio with SVN

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, file-upload, zend-studio

a question about Eclipse/Zend-Studio. I'm trying to use the automatic upload feature but
i'm also using SVN so the projekt-data are in the subfolder trunk.

Now when i save a file it goes to the folder *trunk* on the webserver but it should be on the root-folder of the webserver and i don't know how to tell Zend-Studio to do this.

thx in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the Automatic Upload Properties (Project | Properties | Automatic Upload). Then select a Project Directory:

> A Project Directory is a folder within the Initial Directory that you would like to work with. This is the folder with which you will be transferring data when Uploading and Downloading files and folders to/from the remote server.

See http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/zend-studio.htm#automatic_upload.htm

If this doesn't work and you happen to have shell access to the remote host, [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) the webroot to the trunk folder.

Comment: Sry, but this doesn't help me, is there any way to select the local directory, the folder on the remote server is set correctly.

Comment: @LOstBrOkenKeY The project directory should be trunk.